# posix_kill is unresponsive (no return value)

Tags: php, nginx, posix

I am running `php` file on nginx server. I am having a problem with calling `posix_kill`. I want to send a signal to `SIGINT` but my `posix_kill` seems to be unresponsive cause I am not getting any return value. Unfortunately, I cannot post full code.

EDIT: Any logMessages after `posix_kill` are not working either.

```
$ok = posix_kill($pid, SIGINT);

if($ok) {
    $log_messages[] = 'posix ok';
    logMessage($log_messages);      
} else {
    $log_messages[] = 'posix not ok';
    logMessage($log_messages);  
}
```

And method for `logMessage`

```
function logMessage($messages) {
   $fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'log.txt', 'a+t');
   fwrite($fp, implode(" ", $messages)."\n");
   fclose($fp);
}
```

I checked my log.txt file there are not log statements based on `posix_kill`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're doing very indirect debugging anyway. Why not start by `var_dump()`ing `$ok` right after the function call? I also suggest you double-check that your app is configured in such a way that you can see error messages if any.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yeah, I noticed that I edited the code using  `posix_get_last_error()`

Comment: Now you don't even check `posix_kill()` return value. I'd say that's even more indirect...

Comment: I am welcome to your suggestions if you have one @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Basically I want to check if my posix_kill is working or not

Comment: I'd need to know what additional diagnostic information was provided by my prior suggestions in order to evaluate the possible next steps. Unless I'm missing something, you still don't even know if the function returns `true`, returns `false`, crashes or stalls until PHP times out, and you possibly don't know either if your PHP installation will print or log warnings.

Comment: How to identify if function crashes?

Comment: The code afterwards does not execute and you typically get a weird message like "Access violation at address blah blah" in error logs.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I didn't find any errors in error logs. Where are php error logs located in nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to install an extension to call `posix_kill` so program had no idea what posix is. Anyone who wants to know how to install this extension `yum install php-process`.

Comment: Weird... [php-process](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/devel/rawhide/x86_64/p/php-process-7.2.2-1.fc28.x86_64.html) provides indeed the [posix](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/mageia/cauldron/x86_64/media/core/release/php-posix-7.2.1-1.mga7.x86_64.html) extension. But a missing function always triggers a clear and specific error message like `Fatal error: Call to undefined function posix_kill()`, and its been stated in the question comments that no error messages are being thown.